# how to convert time string (YYYY-MM-DD) into xx Day xx Hr xx min remaining in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert time string (YYYY-MM-DD) into  "xx Day xx Hr xx min remaining" .

How can I do that in dart?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting DateTime to time ago in Dart/Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203376/converting-datetime-to-time-ago-in-dart-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use the Datetime class to find the difference between the two years without using intl to format the date.

You Can also use [Intl Package for same](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.parse('1967-10-12');
Duration dur =  DateTime.now().difference(dob);
String differenceInYears = (dur.inDays/365).floor().toString();
return new Text(differenceInYears + ' years');
```

Comment: say  i have a date like 2020-24-12 and today is 2020-4-23 and i want this " 1 day remaining"